# How to convert string to datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, date-parsing

I have the following string:

```
'2017-08-15T13:34:35Z'
```

How to convert this string to object that I can call  `.isoformat()`?

```
someobject = convert('2017-08-15T13:34:35Z')
someobject.isoformat()
```

How to implement `convert()`?

Comment: You can use the [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method to convert strings to datetimes via a format string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/3286487) to parse a string to date time, then you can:

```
def convert(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

someobject = convert('2017-08-15T13:34:35Z')
print(someobject.isoformat())
```

Comment: Ignoring timezone is wrong. 'Z' is a standard timezone for UTC +0. Try this: `import pytz` `import datetime` `print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-03T14:33:22Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC))`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> date = dateutil.parser.parse('2017-08-15T13:34:35Z', ignoretz=True)
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 15, 13, 34, 35)
>>> date.isoformat()
'2017-08-15T13:34:35'
```

Comment: Ignoring timezone is wrong. 'Z' is a standard timezone for UTC +0. Try this: `import pytz` `import datetime` `print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-03T14:33:22Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC))`